# How to upload Images to Cloudinary using Next.js 13 Route Handler?

Tags: next.js13, cloudinary

Need help uploading to Cloudinary using Route Handlers, I've looked up how to do it with Server Actions but still curious how do it in API routes.

I want this route to create a new Collection document in my mongoDB while simultaneously uploading the image in my Cloudinary. The mongoose query is working perfectly but when I added my upload functions, the route can no longer create mongoDB document and no image is being uploaded to my Cloudinary.

```js
// app/api/postman/collection/route.js
import mongoConnection from "@/lib/mongoose/mongoconnection";
import Collection from "@/lib/mongoose/models/Collection";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { v2 as cloudinary } from "cloudinary";



export async function POST(req, res) {
    await mongoConnection();

    cloudinary.config({
        cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
        api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
        api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
    });

    const { images } = await req.json()
    // array of image paths, example: ("/images/the_lich.png")
    // located in public folder

    console.log(process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME, process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY, process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET) 
    // is getting the correct value

    try {
        // MULTIPLE UPLOADS, looping through an array of image paths
    // for(const image of images) {
    //    const uploads = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(image, {folder: "my-images"});
    //    console.log(uploads);
    // }
        
        // SINGLE UPLOAD, since my multiple upload didn't work I tried
        // doing a single upload, image is located in public folder
    // const upload = await cloudinary.uploader.upload("/images/the_lich.png");

    // console.log(upload);

    const collection = await Collection.create({images})
    if (collection) {
        return NextResponse.json({message: "Success"}, {status: 200});
    } else {
        return NextResponse.json({message: "Failed"}, {status: 500});
    }
        
    } catch (err) {
        return NextResponse.json({message: err.message}, {status: 500});
    }

}
```

I've skimmed through some docs that mentioned something about the public folder but I couldn't find it anymore.

I am using VS Code Postman extension to make the request if that's relevant.